# Why do Yahoo Finance and MSN Money show two different debt/equity ratios?

Tags: accounting, yahoo-finance, online-data-source, microsoft-money

2020-09-06

- AMZN debt to equity ratio on [Yahoo Finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AMZN/key-statistics?p=AMZN): **123.97** (most recent quarter)
- AMZN debt to equity ratio on [MSN Money](https://www.msn.com/en-us/money/stockdetails/financials/nas-amzn/fi-a1nhlh): **0.68** (quarter can't be selected)